# How can set a default value in select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a table and want to set default value

Here is the table:

```
|customers|
  |id|  |name|
    1     ABC
    2     DEF
    3     GHI
    4     JKL
```

Here is the controller:

```
@customers.Customer.all
@customer_selected =   Customer.find(:all,:conditions=>['id=1'])
```

Here is the view, showing all customers

```
<%= select_tag "customer_id", options_for_select(@customers.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]},params[:customer_id].to_i)  %>
```

I tried this line to select customer_id=1 as default value (selected)

```
<%= select_tag "customer_id", options_for_select(@customers.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]},params[:customer_id].to_i),:selected =>@customer_selected.name  %>
```

I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x7f31d8098560>
```

Please somebody can help me ?

Comment: You are pointing to an element in an array. Since array's are collection of elements, you need to either specify the element you want to access to (in this case the first element of the array) or iterate in the array (each, for, etc). t[1].name, t[1].id should work.

Comment: Should your controller code say `@customers = Customer.all`?  That might be your problem rather than the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to bear in mind is that if params[:customer_id] isn't there, then it will be equal to nil, and `nil.to_i` gives 0.  This should be fine as you shouldn't have a customer with id 0 but it's something to be aware of.

I think this should work:

```
<% default_id = params[:customer_id] ? params[:customer_id].to_i : (@customer_selected && @customer_selected.id) %>
<%= select_tag "customer_id", options_for_select(@customers.collect {|t| [t.name,t.id]}, default_id)  %>
```

This will use `params[:customer_id]` if it's defined, or `@customer_selected.id` if `@customer_selected` is defined.

Comment: `(@customer_selected && @customer_selected.id)` would return `true` or `false`, wouldn't it? A simple `@customed_selected.try(:id)` is enough in my opinion

Comment: No, it will return `nil` or the customer id.

Comment: `@customer_selected.try` won't work in rails 2, i think.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip, didn't know the `smth && smth.id` syntax ; http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/Object/try I think it would work (in my irb: `Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.11)`..
`>> @nothing.try(:something)`..`=> nil`

Answer (score 0):

`@customer_selected` is an array, as the error states. This is because `find(:all)` returns an array, even if there is only one result.

You should be able to replace

```
@customer_selected = Customer.find(:all,:conditions=>['id=1'])
```

with

```
@customer_selected = Customer.find(1)
```

Without breaking anything, since `find` looks up objects based on ID anyway and returns a single record rather than a collection.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that this question is about RoR2, so what I suggested may not actually work as I've not tried it in that version.

Comment: It worked with 1 but i replaced it for 2 and didn't worked.
@customer_selected =   Customer.find(2)

Is always starting with 1.